# Get values from different tags using a condition in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have a xml file like this:

```
data =   """<entity type="protein" entityId="A">
    <segment segId="7ddd_A_1_1208" start="1" end="1208">
      <listResidue>
        <residue dbSource="PDBe" dbCoordSys="PDBe" dbResNum="1" dbResName="MET">
          <crossRefDb dbSource="PDB" dbCoordSys="PDBresnum" dbAccessionId="7ddd" dbResNum="null" dbResName="MET" dbChainId="A"/>
          <crossRefDb dbSource="UniProt" dbCoordSys="UniProt" dbAccessionId="P0DTC2" dbResNum="1" dbResName="M"/>
          <crossRefDb dbSource="NCBI" dbCoordSys="UniProt" dbAccessionId="2697049" dbResNum="1" dbResName="M"/>
          <residueDetail dbSource="PDBe" property="Annotation">Not_Observed</residueDetail>
        </residue>
        <residue dbSource="PDBe" dbCoordSys="PDBe" dbResNum="14" dbResName="GLN">
          <crossRefDb dbSource="PDB" dbCoordSys="PDBresnum" dbAccessionId="7ddd" dbResNum="14" dbResName="GLN" dbChainId="A"/>
          <crossRefDb dbSource="UniProt" dbCoordSys="UniProt" dbAccessionId="P0DTC2" dbResNum="13" dbResName="Q"/>
          <crossRefDb dbSource="NCBI" dbCoordSys="UniProt" dbAccessionId="2697049" dbResNum="14" dbResName="Q"/>
          <residueDetail dbSource="PDBe" property="codeSecondaryStructure">T</residueDetail>
          <residueDetail dbSource="PDBe" property="nameSecondaryStructure">loop</residueDetail>
        </residue>
  </entity>
  <entity type="protein" entityId="B">
    <segment segId="7ddd_B_1_1208" start="1" end="1208">
      <listResidue>
        <residue dbSource="PDBe" dbCoordSys="PDBe" dbResNum="1" dbResName="MET">
          <crossRefDb dbSource="PDB" dbCoordSys="PDBresnum" dbAccessionId="7ddd" dbResNum="1" dbResName="MET" dbChainId="B"/>
          <crossRefDb dbSource="UniProt" dbCoordSys="UniProt" dbAccessionId="PXCDT" dbResNum="1" dbResName="M"/>
          <crossRefDb dbSource="NCBI" dbCoordSys="UniProt" dbAccessionId="2697049" dbResNum="1" dbResName="M"/>
          <residueDetail dbSource="PDBe" property="Annotation">Not_Observed</residueDetail>
        </residue>
        <residue dbSource="PDBe" dbCoordSys="PDBe" dbResNum="16" dbResName="VAL">
          <crossRefDb dbSource="PDB" dbCoordSys="PDBresnum" dbAccessionId="7ddd" dbResNum="16" dbResName="VAL" dbChainId="B"/>
          <crossRefDb dbSource="UniProt" dbCoordSys="UniProt" dbAccessionId="P0DTC2" dbResNum="16" dbResName="V"/>
          <crossRefDb dbSource="NCBI" dbCoordSys="UniProt" dbAccessionId="2697049" dbResNum="16" dbResName="V"/>
          <residueDetail dbSource="PDBe" property="codeSecondaryStructure">T</residueDetail>
          <residueDetail dbSource="PDBe" property="nameSecondaryStructure">loop</residueDetail>
        </residue>"""
```

What I am trying to do is retrieve the *dbResNum* value from the same line as dbSource="PDB" and dbSource="UniProt". But, I want those values only if it doesn't have dbResNum="null" in the dbSource="PDB" line and it doesn't have any different value than dbAccessionId="P0DTC2" in the dbSource="UniProt" line. So, my output would be something like this:

PDB_Res = '13', '16'
Uniprot_Res = '14, '16'

My code for trying to do that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
def not_null(dbresnum):
    return dbresnum and not re.compile("null").search(dbresnum)

xml_file = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
XML_without_null = xml_file.find_all(dbresnum=not_null)
for cross in XML_without_null:
    if cross('crossrefdb', {"dbaccessionid":"P0DTC2"}):
        Uniprot_id = cross['dbresnum']
    if cross('crossrefdb', {"dbsource":"PDB"}):
        PDB_id = cross['dbresnum']
```

The problem is the function not_null is not working properly. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Is all handling of crossRefDb elements independent from each other or if a given residue has a child crossRefDb dbresnum = "null" are all crossRefDb elements in that residue group ignored ?? Why isn't dbResNum=1 included in your expected output ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the welcome. So yes, If I get a null in dbresnum in the same line as dbSource="PDB", it will skip any dbresnum from that child. So, the script supposes to ignore the first child, because it gets a null in dbresnum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, need to change the parser from "lxml" to "xml".
*lxml* is an alias for *lxml.html.soupparser*, which is for HTML.

Also note the XML snippet in your question is an invalid XML file with no closing segment or listResidue elements. There is no root XML element, only 2 entity elements which is not valid. BeautifulSoup handles invalid documents but always recommended to start with a valid XML document if possible.

If want to skip an entire *residue* group and all *crossRefDb* children in it then need to iterate over all *residue* and check if any child *crossRefDb* has has a null in dbresnum in the same line as dbSource="PDB".

Try something like this:

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<entity ...'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
uni_res = set()
pdb_res = set()
for residue in soup.find_all('residue'):
    if residue.find('crossRefDb', {'dbSource': 'PDB', 'dbResNum': 'null'}):
        continue
    for cross in residue.find_all('crossRefDb'):
        res_num = cross.get('dbResNum')
        if cross.get("dbAccessionId") == "P0DTC2":
            uni_res.add(res_num)
        if cross.get("dbSource") == "PDB":
            pdb_res.add(res_num)

print("PDB_Res =", pdb_res, "Uniprot =", uni_res)
```

**Output:**

```
PDB_Res = {'1', '16', '14'} Uniprot_Res = {'16', '13'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The problem is it should skip the first child because it gets a null in the dbresnum tag. And since I am getting a dbAccession Id="PXCDT" in another child, it also needs to skip that. So, my output should be like that: PDB_Res= {'14', 16'} Uniprot_Res= {'13', '16'}

Comment: I have changed a little your solution, I added this line: if residue.find('crossRefDb', {'dbSource': 'UniProt', 'dbAccessionId': "P0DTC2"''}), since I only want values if the dbAccessionId is "P0DTC2"'. But thank you so much, your example helped to resolve the problem. I realy appreciated.